# Joda DateTime as String to java.sql.Date in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: java, sql, datetime, db2, jodatime

I am getting a Joda DateTime as a parameter in a rest call.

The value is

```
20160803-01-01T00:00:00.000 05:30
```

I want to use it as a parameter in a db2 database query which expects it to be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

How do I read Joda DateTime which would be as a String in the rest call?
How do I convert that to java.sql.Date in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the database using a text based column type?  It should be using a date based column type then it's just simple process of using a `java.sql.Date`, which can be accomplished by using JodaTime (or Java 8's Time API) to parse the value to a `LocalDateTime` value (or equivilant), using it to create a `java.util.Date` and using that to create a `java.sql.Date`.  Very common, you should research each part and see if you can piece together a solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I am trying to use DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); to parse above String but getting Invalid Format exception. How to find out the correct pattern for my String ?

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` != `20160803-01-01T00:00:00.000 05:30`, the pattern must match the value format

Comment: MadProgrammer is right--just what _is_ that extra 05:30 doing there?